# Substitute marker with plugin in TS

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I'm tring to create my first typo template, but when I try to substitute a marker with an existing template, it results as a blank space in the corresponding page.

```
    page = PAGE
    page {
    typeNum = 0
    10 = TEMPLATE
    10 {
        relPathPrefix = fileadmin/template/
        template < plugin.tx_rlmptmplselector_pi1
        workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY
        marks {
            LEADER_BANNER = RECORDS
            LEADER_BANNER {
                tables=tt_content
                source=93
            }
        }
    }
```

this isn't the whole ts code, if u need it, just ask.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know thats not the perfect answer for your problem, but i would really recommend to use TemplaVoila instead of markers. Marker are obsolete. If your really new in TYPO3 use TemplaVoila there are thousands of advantages you will see. And if there some questions feel free to ask.